# Why does an airflow job still get scheduled on daily when the setting in the dag says None

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a dag that I am trying to set to manual run only.
I do not want this thing to run automatically.

In the dag it says:

```
args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': dates.days_ago(1),
    'email': ['email@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_success': True,
    'schedule_interval': None,
}

dag = models.DAG(
    dag_id='myDag',
    default_args=args
)
```

However in the Airflow Manager, it shows `1 day, 0:00:00`

And it still attempts to run.

How do I make this a manually called dag only?
Thanks!

Update:

Here's the changes I made:

```
args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 12, 29),
    'email': ['sinistersparrow1701@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_success': True,
    'schedule_interval': None,
}

dag = models.DAG(
    dag_id='API_DataFinder_Lookup_Ingestion_V1',
    default_args=args
)
```

no change in Airflow.
Still shows daily.

What else can I do?

Comment: Dag versioning is a weak-point of airflow - can you try incrementing the `dag_id` (from "myDag" to "myDag_v1" or something) and then seeing its behaviour? Changing the `start_date` or `schedule_interval` and not incrementing the "version" is a common [gotcha](https://gtoonstra.github.io/etl-with-airflow/gotchas.html)

Comment: Change your `'start_date'` to a static date like `'start_date': datetime(2019, 12, 29) #year month day`.

Comment: updated the top.  didn't change.  any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can put "schedule_interval" in the section of "dag" instead of "args".

Try this:

```
args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 12, 29),
    'email': ['sinistersparrow1701@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_success': True
}

dag = models.DAG(
    dag_id='API_DataFinder_Lookup_Ingestion_V1',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval=None
)
```